# How to replace preview of post with full content using jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a php variable `$preview` I save about 4 lines of a post without any tags. In the `$full` I save full of the post with tags.

This is what I used to have, an expand/collapse toogle http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/22/ when I was saving the entire post. But it doesn't look good without tags so I need to go one step forward.

My question is how to change it, so it shows `$preview` until the user clicks on expand and show the `$full` post?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my version: http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/28/

I've used separate blocks for preview and full content and `fadeIn\fadeOut` for animating it

Comment: Thank you for this, but how do I keep separating image from the expanded text? I mean I don't want the text to go in the bottom of the image.

Comment: Add `padding-left` to your content. I've updated [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/28/)

Comment: Thanks again for this. I just noticed that if I have many posts it does not work correctly. I updated it here. Maybe a `closest` ?

Comment: My bad, it does work but I can not collapse all posts except the first

Comment: I've updated a little and it work at least with 3 post: http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/33/. The only thing is to change using of ID's to classes becuase of it should not be 2 element with the same ID on the page.

Comment: I've added the parent element of the post for searching nested items: `$('#thepost-preview', $(this).closest('div.post'))`

Answer (score 1):

Put two  elements in the output HTML of your PHP script; one containing the preview and one containing the full text. Then just hide the full one (CSS "display: none;") and on a click show the  element containing the full text while hiding the element containing just the preview?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the html a little you could save the preview in a div and the full message in another and then toggle the dive like this:

```
<div id="post">

    <div id="image">
        <img alt="image" border="0" src="here-goes-an-image.png">
    </div>

    <div id="text expanded">
        <a href="#" class="toggle">(expand)</a>
        <h2><a href="#" target="_blank">This is the title</a></h2>
        <div id="authorANDtime">
            <b>from <a href="#">author</a>, 22 mins ago.</b>
        </div>
                <div id='preview'>Here goes the preview vHere goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview Here goes the preview </div>  
        <div id="thepost">
            Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post. Here goes the content of the post.
            HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT. HERE IS THE HIDDEN CONTENT.
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

$('#thepost').hide();
$('.toggle').click(function(){

    $('#preview').toggle();
    $('#thepost').toggle();
    if($('#preview').is(':visible')){
        $(this).text('(expand)');
    }else{
        $(this).text('(collapse)');
    }
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/27/

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to keep text out of going at the bottom of the image?

Comment: As  you can see here http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4F8Q/30/ if I have multiple posts it does not work. How to make it work ?